# Is it safe to show a session activity summary after logout?

Tags: web-application

As noted in DBS' internet banking system, it shows a summary ***after*** I clicked logout. It gives an activity log performed during the session. Which I thought, during the logout process, the current session (at server side) should be invalidated, cookie (at client side - browser) should be expired / cleared, thus the current user should no longer be identifiable after a successful logout process.

- http://www.dbs.com.hk/personal/notice_20160624.page
- https://internet-banking.dbs.com.cn/cn/javahelpweb/default/ARCAppNmBusBk/bbHelp/logout.htm

The summary of session activity log contradicts to my understanding. The application would still be able to identify the user after a successful logout process. Though one may suggest that the application would treat the "logout" process merely negating an authorization (boolean) flag for some critical functions. Others could also suggest that the summary was stored on client's browser before logout and presented to user after logout. However I am still skeptical that how the summary be treated after I leave the page. Is there any security risk for such practice?

Comment: Are you not over-thinking this? Isn't it just that the details are fetched as part of the same request that a logout was performed? The details can be retrieved at any point, in fact.